# Intercept and convert all alerts to notifications

Tags: javascript, jquery, gritter

So I'm using [Gritter](http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/) for notifications throughout a site, and was wondering if there was a simple way to intersept all the alert() s thrown by any script, with jQuery, and reformat the value of the alert to the body of a Gritter notification?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace the `alert` function and do whatever you want with the arguments:

```
window.alert = function (message) {
    $.gritter.add({
        title: 'Message for you sir!',
        text: message
    });
};
```

Comment: Browsers should probably have this by default :D